# Looking for recommendations to improve this Java code

Tags: java, performance

I am trying to append indexes with constants and get some sql. Currently I am just iterating over a list using for loop. I am looking for better ways of doing the same.

```java
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
Integer index = 0;

for (String str : listToIterate) {
    String param1 = "PARAM" + index;
    String prefixParam1 = "PARAM_PREFIX" + index;
    list1.add(getSomeParameterisedSql(param1, prefixParam1, str));
    index = index + 1;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to have better ways ? Are you having any performance issues ? Or you want to shorten the code ?

Comment: What is wrong with the current method?

Comment: How about formatting/indentation? That would be a guaranteed win.

Comment: For general help on writing code you could have a look at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could use a regular for loop instead of a for-each and use the counter as index, but that would just shorten this code by two lines.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are using Java 8, if so below code might work for you

```
    List<String> listOfSqls = IntStream.range(0,listToIterate.size())
        .mapToObj(index -> getSomeParameterisedSql("PARAM" + index, "PARAM_PREFIX" + index, listToIterate.get(index)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I am using Java11

Comment: [@itisha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6155341/itisha) Java 11 is backwards compatible with Java 8.